# Are there browsers whose viewport-width (measured in css-pixel) can be a fractional number?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible, that the width of a browsers viewport, measured in px, is not a whole number?

There are devices (i.e. with apples retina display), where a "logical pixel" is divided into two "physical pixels" in each direction, which makes an area of 2x2=4 physical pixels that are responsible for one logical pixel.

Suppose you have a website about Captain Kirk, and you have a header like this:

```
<h1 class="small">Kirk</h1>
<h1 class="medium">Captain James T. Kirk</h1>
<h1 class="large">James Tiberius Kirk, Captain of starship USS Enterprise</h1>
```

And this css with media queries makes it possible, that only one of those three headings will be visible:

```
.small {
    display: block;
}

.medium .large {
    display: none;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 400px) {
    .small {
        display: none;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 899px) {
    .medium {
        display: block;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
    .large {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

As you can see, the element for the size "medium" is displayed up to a (logical) viewport-size of 899 pixel. If the viewport has a width of 900 logical pixels (or more), the element with class "large" is displayed instead.

But on a device where each logical pixels is divided into 2 physical pixels, the boundaries defined in the stylesheet correspond with 1798 respectively 1800 physical pixels.

And here comes my question:

**Is it possible** on such devices, **that the browsers viewport has a with of 1799 physical pixels, which means 899.5 css-pixels?**

If this is possible, then we have a viewport that is 899.5 logical pixels wide. This is greater than 899 and smaller than 900, and this means for the example from above, that in this size neither the medium, nor the large element will be displayed.

And here is another formulation of the same question:

In css-stylesheets: **Is it save to have media-queries where the sizes of elements are coded like in my example?**

If it is not safe (because there exists viewports with widths of 899.5 pixels): What is a safe method to write media-queries that really do what the above css is meant to do?

Comment: Are we really trying to split a pixel? lol

Comment: Question: why the `and (max-width: 899px)`? Why not remove that part and add `.medium { display: none; }` to the next query? Then I believe you'll be covered?

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith: Not I am trying. Apple does it since 2010 in its iPhones and since 2012 also in some of its MacBooks.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast no they don't, they have a high ppi which is about double the browser's ppi, and is why for example the iphone actual with is 640px but the browser view port is only 320px, a percentage of pixels gets rounded, splitting a pixel is not possible, some browsers will show something however it is very unreliable.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith: It is clear on an iPhone, because you can't resize the browser's window on an iPhone. But you can resize the browser's window on a MacBook Pro that has a retina display. I just don't know if you can end with a viewport size of 899.5 pixel, or if the width is guaranteed to be always a whole number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Media Queries only trigger on whole pixels. It will trigger when it hits the nearest whole number.

So if your query were written:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
    .large {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

The query wont function unless the screen width is 900px +. It would use the query that includes values up to 899.9999999.... (infinite) px unless the screen width hits 900px or greater.

Answer (score 0):

Those media queries are safe. Browsers don't interpret their widths at half/fractional pixels.

Comment: Not entirely true. Browsers can do measurements in half pixels - we do it all the time in CSS.

Example: 

`body{
text-size: 14px;
}

h1{
text-size: 2.2rem
}`

In this case, the H1 text would be 30.8px;
The browser simply rounds to the closest whole pixel - or 31px.
The float is interpreted and rounded as a whole number.

Comment: But the questions is whether browsers can interpret viewport width as a fractional number. It could be that the screen size **has** to be a whole number, even though other sizes can be fractional.